# Source code for os.remove() in python

Tags: python

Where is the source code for os.remove() in python? In the following file "https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py", some functions of "os" are given but I couldn't find the definition for "remove".

Basically I want to check how remove() is implemented in python.

Answer (score 2):

It's here for POSIX:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69dccc397ad1522309f15e4d5e0afe68b782ba66/Modules/posixmodule.c#L4374

At the top of `os.py` you see it imports a module named `posix` if it's running on POSIX:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py#L64

```
if 'posix' in _names:
# ...
    import posix
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(posix))
```

It is a built-in module defined at the bottom of `posixmodule.c`:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/69dccc397ad1522309f15e4d5e0afe68b782ba66/Modules/posixmodule.c#L13698

```
#define MODNAME "posix"

// ...

static struct PyModuleDef posixmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    MODNAME,
// ...
};

// ...

PyMODINIT_FUNC
INITFUNC(void)
{
// ...
    m = PyModule_Create(&posixmodule);
// ...
```